# Publishing web site: the resource cannot be found error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, error-handling, publishing

Hi everyone when I publish my web site via ISS I get this error as you can see at below

```
Server Error in '/WebCity' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /WebCity/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
```

Comment: That only tells that website isn't published. Please describe steps you've made.

Comment: Bit more information required... does the URL exists? Do you have permission to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit: `Requested URL: /WebCity/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` means it is looking for that specific URL, which it shouldn't be.

i.e. It looks like you've navigated to `http://domain.com/WebCity/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` instead of just `http://domain.com/WebCity/` or whatever it should be.

Either you are entering the wrong URL into the browser, or the MVC Framework is not installed on the server.

If the framework is not installed, don't worry. See here for Phil Haack's notes on how to `bin deploy` it: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx